# get value from another tabe for two same field in a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-web-api

i have a view where i get data from a table named 'PromotionHistory'. But in my table i stored ID of Designation. In Designation table i have DesignationName field and DesignationID. Both table have relation. I am using Web Api.

[image: Data from PromotionHistory table]
My code-

```
     [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/EmployeeApi/GetPromotionReport/")]
        public object  GetPromotionReport()
        {
            List<PromotionHistory> finalData;
            //var proReport = db.PromotionHistories.Include(e => e.Designation).Include(e => e.Employee);

            IEnumerable<PromotionHistory> pro = (from st in db.PromotionHistories select st).ToList();

            foreach (PromotionHistory proH in pro)
            {

                var preD = proH.PreviousDesigID;
                var currentD = proH.CurrentDesigID;

                var preDName=(from dd in db.Designations where dd.DesignationID==preD select new{dd.DesignationName}).FirstOrDefault() ;
                var CurrentDName=(from dd in db.Designations where dd.DesignationID==currentD select new{dd.DesignationName}).FirstOrDefault();
  var cc = (from proHis in db.PromotionHistories

                         select new
                         {
                             proHis.PromotionID,
                             proHis.EmployeeID

                         }

                             ).ToList();

                finalData.AddRange(cc);
                finalData.Add(preDName);


            }
```

> I want to get DesignationName instead of ID for the two field (previousPost, Current Post-see image)
>   How can i make Linq or SQL query in ASP Web Api as i am using Ajax.

What i want::
PromotionID ,EmplyeeID ,PromotionDate, Previous Designation , Current Designation

Comment: what is the code which you have made to retrieve ? update that with the post. Before asking a question. Have a read with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can add another class, and return list of the new class. like this

```
public object GetPromotionReport()
    {
        List<PromotionHistorywithNames> finalData;
        finalData = (from st in db.PromotionHistories
                     select new PromotionHistorywithNames
                     {
                         PromotionID = st.PromotionID,
                         EmployeeID = st.EmployeeID,
                         PreviousPost = (from dd in db.Designations where dd.DesignationID == st.Promotion select dd.DesignationName).FirstOrDefault(),
                         CurrentPost = (from dd in db.Designations where dd.DesignationID == st.currentD select dd.DesignationName).FirstOrDefault()
                     }).ToList();
        return finalData;
    }
```

and the class like this

```
    public class PromotionHistorywithNames{
        public int PromotionID{set;get;}
        public int EmployeeID{set;get;}
        public DateTime Promotion{set;get;}
        public string PreviousPost{set;get;}
        public string CurrentPost{set;get;}
    }
```

Comment: You guy is awesome awesome awesome awesome!!! If i have access to vote , i would vote you thousand times. Your answer not only give my solution but it give me new logic. I am very proud of you. Can i have your mail? nuruddinfawel is my gmail address.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my annonymous type problem by this: It can be done without model class

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("api/MemberApi/GetMembersWithLink/")]
    public object GetMembersWithLink()
    {


        var member = (from members in db.Members
                      where members.Status == 1
                      select new
                      {
                          members.MemberName,
                          members.Position,
                          members.Phone,
                          members.Picture,
                          members.MotherName,
                          members.Village,
                          members.Email,
                          linkName = (from gg in db.Members where gg.MemberID==  members.Link select gg.MemberName).FirstOrDefault()
                      }).ToList();


        return member.AsEnumerable();
    }
```